# How to get element properties in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to get the height of the parent container element, to use as a height of an SVG background element.

Is there a way to get and pass this property?

I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined"

```js
const Services = ({ classes }) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container} ref="container">//Element I want the height of
            <div className={classes.BGContainer}>
                <BGSVG width={'210'} height={this.refs.container.height} color={'blue'} />//Where I want to pass height to
            </div>
            <div className={classes.Services}>
                {services.map((e, i) => (
                    <ServiceItem
                        title={e.title}
                        icon={e.icon}
                        info={e.info}
                        inverted={i % 2 === 1 ? true : false}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: if you console log this.refs.container inside this functional component what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a functional component, you need to use the React Hook called [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) like this:

```
const TextInputWithFocusButton = (props) => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

you will see if you  log out `inputEl` that a reference to the input element is logged. DOM element references allow you to access most properties of the particular DOM element referenced.

Comment: This seems to have gotten rid of the error I was getting, and I can now log the element in the console. But when I try to access ref.current.height or ref.current.clientHeight I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null"

Comment: That can happen based on the hierarchy of your components, which influences how and when a component will render, and with what. Something easy to try here, is something like `ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight` and assign the result. I'm guessing you are also seeing multiple console logs with just one console.log statement?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bound "this". Try height={() => this.refs.container.height}

Comment: Doing this give me "Function components cannot have refs. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?" as an error.

Comment: Yes, you can only use refs on class components, that was the next thing I wanted to point out. Convert it to a class e.g. "class Services extends React.Component". If you want to stick with the functional route, Stephen Collins' answer may be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If your Services component is inside lets say ServicesWrapper Component, what you should do is put on it

```
`servicesWrapperContainerRef = React.createRef()`;
```

Then, on JSX of wrapper component place

```
`ref={this.servicesWrapperContainerRef}`
```

and then, pass that as a prop to the Services component like this 
const Services = ({ classes, servicesWrapperContainerRef }) and then you can use it to find out the parents height

```
`height={this.props.servicesWrapperContainerRef.current.clientHeight}`
```

Comment: I'm wanting the height of an element from inside the same component. I think I've edited in this way but I'm still getting the error about React.forwardRef()

Comment: Oh, than you need to transform it from functional component to class component and then put created  ref on the same div you did now.